# how to create a min,max, and average methods in a generic class?(Java)

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem in implementing those methods(min, max, and average ) in my generic class. I have already specified the return type as E but it seems hard to get it to work. if anyone has an example for implementing those methods I would really appreciate it.

```
public E ave() {

        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            total = (total + bag[i]);
        }
        int ave = (total / size());
        return ave;
    }

    public int minimum() {
        int min = bag[0];
        for (int a = 1; a < size(); a++) {
            if (bag[a] < min) {
                min = bag[a];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide your latest attempt?

Comment: Not providing the code that you've tried is also a reason for downvote.

Comment: Motivation for the question has nothing to do with voting, but rather question quality is all that matters.

Comment: What should happen if `E` is a class such as `String`, for which `min`, `max` and `average` don't really make sense?

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections as you appear to be confused as to how this site works. It can help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: you can use `Comparator<E>` to get min or max, but average? only if `E extends Number`

Comment: Generic class does not mean you have to return it's type by method. just change your return type of average to `double` and also change your ave evaluation to `double ave = (double) total / size();`

Comment: @matoni I tried this way before but I got a problem with addition, (int+Object)

Comment: What is `bag` an array of? Is it declared `E[] bag`?

Comment: you have to add in your code more details (at least bag[] field declaration).

Comment: it's declared as Object[] bag, so that it can hold integers, double, float

Comment: `Object[]` is not suficient for you as it hides your custom objects behind `Object` interface (only `Object` class methods are visible to you). So how to resolve it? Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First define some interface with `int` method that will be used by your math class.

```
public interface IntHolder {
    int getIntValue();
}
```

Add contraint to generic `E` such that `E extends IntHolder` i. e. only `IntHolder` implementations can be added in `GenericArrayMath`. Since all objects are guarenteed to be of `IntHolder` type, now you can use in your math methods `getIntValue()` of given object.

Note, unconstrained `E` can by anything so it is impossible to predict by compiler object fields/methods. The only thing that you can be sure about `E` is, that it extends `Object` (as all classes extends `Object` by default), thus you can only use `Object`'s methods.

```
public class GenericArrayMath<E extends IntHolder> {

    private final E[] bag;

    public GenericArrayMath(Class<E> clazz, int length) {
        bag = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, length)
    }

    public void set(int i, E e) { bag[i] = e; }

    public int min() {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++) {
            if (bag[i] == null) { continue; } // skip
            if (bag[i] < min) { min = bag[i]; }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public int max() {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++) {
            if (bag[i] == null) { continue; } // skip
            if (bag[i] > max) { max = bag[i]; }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public double avg() {
        double sum = 0;
        int nonNullCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bag.length; i++) {
            if (bag[i] == null) { continue; } // skip
            sum += bag[i].getIntValue();
            nonNullCount++;
        }
        return sum / nonNullCount;
    }
}
```

Example of `IntHolder` implementation:

```
public class Person extends IntHolder {
    public final String name;
    public final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntValue() { return age; }
}
```

and finally `GenericArrayMath` usage:

```
GenericArrayMath<Person> gam = new GenericArrayMath<>(Person.class, 3);
gam.set(0, new Person("a", 20));
gam.set(1, new Person("b", 30));
gam.set(2, new Person("c", 40));

int minAge = gam.min();
int maxAge = gam.max();
double avgAge = gam.avg();
```

Hope it helps.